# How to bend a cylinder into a semi circle

Tags: objects

I am wondering what is the best and EASIEST method to create a mesh for part of a hand rail which has a semi circular bend in it. The hand rail is round so I will use a cylinder?
Refer to image below where the part of the handrail has been marked in PINK with an arrow pointing to it. Yes it seems to be an irregular bend (tighter bend near the top than near the bottom) but just a regular shaped semi circle will be ok unless it is simple to change from a regular semicircle.
[image]

Comment: Use round bevel option on a curve would be a super simple way, not sure if it's the "easiest" though. It would give you a lot of simplicity to get nice rounded shapes.

Comment: Thanks  (at last I found a suitable youtube video (for what I am trying to achieve) and this is how I did it (I chose not to use 'answer you question' in case there is a better more correct method). 1 Add cylinder and set dimensions as required 2 (edit mode) select bottom face and set cursor to selected then (object mode) set origin to 3d cursor 3. Apply all transforms  4 Add Simple Deform modifier  and select Bend  5  (edit mode) set cuts to required number   6  set Angle top 180.    BUT how can I ensure that the ends of the semi circle bent cylinder are a particular distance apart?

Comment: That would be a lot easier using a curve. You could snap one end point to the other, then move it a fixed amount

Comment: Thanks.  Yes that would work but also using my mathematical memories I can calculate the height of the cylinder to be bent into a semi circle as follows (using Pi to calculate the circumference of a circle using the diameter)  cylinder height required before bending (Z axis) = distance required between ends minus half diameter of cylinder  multiplied by 22  and divided by  14. Well that worked perfectly for me.